# How to lookup EJB deployed on Wildfly 11 using IIOP/CORBA?

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, corba, iiop

I want to lookup EJB deplpoyed on Wildfly server using IIOP/CORBA.

On Payara Server I am able to do this using below configuration:

> Payara JNDI lookup

```
Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
jndiProperties.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
jndiProperties.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
javax.naming.Context c = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
```

what properties needs to be set for Wildfly? I looked into many samples but they are using **http-remoting**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I checked this too. On link it is mentioned that **To enable IIOP you must have the JacORB subsystem installed, and the <iiop/> element present in the ejb3 subsystem configuration**. In **standalone-full.xml** i made iiop `enable-by-default="true"` but i didn't find anything related to **JacORB**

Comment: @ElliottFrisch However, I tried to lookup the bean using CORBA url as below **`c.lookup("corbaname::localhost:3528/NameService#LegecySystem-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/LegecySystem-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/LegecyBean!com.test.remote.ConnectionRemote");`** it gives me error `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]`

Comment: If i use **http-remote** and pass **ejb:LegecySystem‌​-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/Le‌​gecySystem-ejb-1.0-S‌​NAPSHOT/LegecyBean!c‌​om.test.remote.Conne‌​ctionRemote** to lookup it works perfectly.  can you please tell what is missing in case of IIOP ?

Comment: if you're only using `jacorb` I believe you can just run that stand-alone -- probably much simpler.